# UITableView Causing Image to Enlarge

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

So I have a `UITableView` inside of a `UIViewController`. Without the tableView, the simulator looks like this:
[image]

However when the Table View is connected it looks like this:
[image]

with an error of:

```
2015-03-19 02:08:56.086 CPX[55379:5813118] Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
2015-03-19 02:08:56.482 CPX[55379:5813118] Failed to set (autostart) user defined inspected property on (UIView): [<UIView 0x7f8fa8da28c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key autostart.
2015-03-19 02:08:56.483 CPX[55379:5813118] Failed to set (animation) user defined inspected property on (UIView): [<UIView 0x7f8fa8da28c0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key animation.
```

**Why is this happening, and how can I prevent the resizing of the image?**

Thankyou for your help!

Comment: Are you setting background image for tableview? or it is the imageview's background image over your view?

Comment: @UmangBista It is a `UIImageView` over the `UIViewController`.

Comment: Are you using auto-layouts?

Comment: @UmangBista Yes, I am. I have set the constraints of the `UIImageView` but not the `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your auto resizeing or autolayout class are cheched in storyboard or in xib that is causing the problem you can simply un check it and handle the frame according to different iphone size's.

Comment: Where can I look to uncheck it? I can't find where.

Comment: @stevenR - do you need auto-layout feature in your app?

Comment: @UmangBista I think I am using auto layout? Where can I check for sure?

Comment: I mean do you want to use it? Because if you are using it, it will be better for you app, since your app will work well in all kind of devices. If you don't want to use it just uncheck this on right side pane's(inspector pane) first option's view.

Comment: Please try unchecking 'auto-resize classes' from the above mentioned inspector area. Since setting 'autolayout' requires graphical(screen-shot) assistance. I'm not near my mac,so, I can't help you on this for now.

Answer (score 0):

you can prevent resizing of Image using Auto-Layout Constraints,
i suggest that just add height and width with top and trailing space if your image has fix size otherwise you have to add constraints as per your relative views like if you won't your image to extends height and width according to another view then add constraints relative that view.

if you can show your other view than i can suggest more specifically which constraints you have to add.